# Restoring site from another server doesn't seem to copy permissions

Tags: 2007, permissions, backup, restore

I have backed up a site, from development box, and restored it to another, live, server. Everything seems to have been copied correctly. The site looks the same, and when I look in the permissions, I, and several others, seem to have the correct permissions.

However, I cannot do anything on the site. I can't post announcements, add files, change permissions. Neither can anyone else, even though, as I say, it looks like all the permissions are correct.

Any ideas?

For reference this is the process I used for the backup and restore.

Lock the sharepoint site against changes:

```
stsadm.exe -o setsitelock -url <dev server> -lock readonly
```

Backup the sharepoint site:

```
stsadm.exe -o backup -url <dev server> -filename "c:\spbackup\sharepoint17_11_2011.dat" -overwrite
```

Unlock the Sharepoint site after backup:

```
stsadm.exe -o setsitelock -url <dev server> -lock none
```

Copy the files from c:\spbackup on dev server to live server and run the following:

Restore Sharepoint Backup

```
stsadm.exe -o restore -url <live server> -filename c:\spbackup\sharepoint02112011.dat -overwrite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you locked the site before backing up, I'm pretty sure that the backed up site will also be locked.

I'd run the unlock command on the restored site and see if that fixes the issue ;-)